# Arduino SIM800L Firestore database security rules

Tags: arduino, google-cloud-firestore

I want to post data in a Firestore database using Arduino with the SIM800L module.

I have already done a test in which I use Firebase Database Realtime which works well but without configuring the security.

Now I use a Firestore database by configuring security.
I read the official documentation but I do not know how Arduino should make the request to enter the authentication information.

Answer (score 0):

Update my question.

here is the code that I use with the Realtime database without security configuration.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.send('identifiant: ' + req.body.identifiant);
});

exports.insertMesure = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const identifiant = req.body.identifiant;
    const temperatureAir = req.body.temperatureAir;
    const humiditeSol = req.body.humiditeSol;
    const humiditeAir = req.body.humiditeAir;
    const niveauEau = req.body.niveauEau;
    const phSol = req.body.phSol;
    const dateMesure = Date.now();

    const mesure = {
        temperatureAir: temperatureAir,
        humiditeSol: humiditeSol,
        humiditeAir: humiditeAir,
        niveauEau: niveauEau,
        phSol: phSol,
        dateMesure: dateMesure
    };

    const dbRef = admin.database().ref('/users/' + identifiant + '/mesures');
    dbRef.push(mesure)
    .then(() => {
        return res.status(200).send('oK');
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send('Error: ' + err);
    });

});
```

The structure of my database:

```
- users
  - {user_id}
   - mesures
```

Replaced

> user_id

by the identifier attribute

> identifiant

of the request sent by Arduino